# My Id increments, however it applies that value to the previous Ids, which is not what I. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists, increment

I'm trying to create and append new `li` to my `ul`, however I want to differentiate them with unique `Id`s from 0 to however long it ends up being. This is because I want to call on the number and assign to a variable such as I to pull information from say `Contactlist[i]`, when I click on that `li`. Maybe using the `Id` isn't the best way...

This is a portion of my code where I think the issue lies, when the `li` is being created. Pointer was set to -1, because I was just trying various ways to get my wanted result, as well as the location of `Pointer++`.

```
var Pointer = -1;
var form  = document.getElementById('contact');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(){
  Pointer++;
    if (form.person.value,form.phone.value,form.email.value === '') {
  } else {
   if(!window.contactList){ //check if we already have a contact list
   window.contactList=$ab(form.person.value,form.phone.value,form.email.value);
  } else {
  //saves new values rather than deleting old ones as well
    contactList.addNewContact(form.person.value,form.phone.value,form.email.value);
  }
 }
      var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.setAttribute("href", "#");
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      li.id=(Pointer);
  var inputValue = form.person.value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  a.appendChild(t);
  li.appendChild(a);
  if (inputValue,form.phone.value,form.email.value === '') {
    alert("You must provide information!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);

  for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function() {
      var div = this.parentElement;
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

    form.person.value = '';
    form.phone.value = '';
    form.email.value = '';

   event.preventDefault();
});
```

Here's the rest of the JavaScript code that goes before the above portion. Sorry I know the formatting awful...

```
// Create a "close" button and append it to each list item
var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
  }

// Click on a close button to hide the current list item
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function() {
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

// Create a new list item when clicking on the "Add" button

function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
      if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          li[i].style.display = "";
          } 
      else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }

function AddElement(){
    document.getElementById('myInfo').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('contact-panel').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('show-panel').style.display = 'none';
    }

;(function(global){
    var AddressBook = function(name,phone,email){
    return new AddressBook.init(name,phone,email);
    };

    AddressBook.prototype = {
     //default functions
        data:[
        //add data here
           ],
     searchResults:[

          ],
     addNewContact:function(name,phone,email){
       this.data.push({
         name: name,
         phone: phone,
         email:email
          });
       return this;
       },
     save:function(){
       //save to local storage. This isn't hugely necessary

          },
     returnAll:function(){
       return this.data;
     },
     displayData:function(){
       this.log(this.data);
       return this;
     },
     log:function(data){
       console.log(data);
       return this;
     },
   } 

   AddressBook.init=function(name,phone,email){
     var self = this;
     //set up the address book
     if(name || phone || email){
       self.addNewContact(name || "", phone||"", email||"");
     }

   }

   AddressBook.init.prototype = AddressBook.prototype;

  global.AddressBook = $ab = AddressBook;
})(window);

if(!window.contactList){ //check if we already have a contact list
   window.contactList=$ab();
  }
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName = 'LI') {
    document.getElementById('myInfo').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('show-panel').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('contact-panel').style.display = 'none';
  }
  var EleID = +ev.target.id;
  if(window.contactList){ //check if we already have a contact list
     document.getElementById('show-panel').innerHTML = '';
   var contacts = contactList.returnAll();
    console.log(contacts);
    if(contacts.length>0){
      for(var i = 0;i<contacts.length;i++){
      document.getElementById('show-panel').innerHTML +='<divclass="contact-item">Name:'+contacts[i].name+'<br>Phone:'+contacts[i].phone+'<br>Email:'+contacts[i].email+EleID+'</div><hr>';
    }
    }else{
      document.getElementById('show-panel').innerHTML += '<div class="contact-item">You have no contacts. Why not add  a few?</div><hr>';
    }
  }
}, false);
```

I want first `li` `id` to be 0, second to be 1, and so on.

first creation results in `Id` of 0, second creation results in both first and second `li` having `Id` of 1....

[Result after only one li creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FASrg.png)

[Result after second li creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkeCO.png)

Comment: could you please share the html portion of the code?

Comment: That indentation on that code makes it hard to read.

Comment: `Maybe using the Id isn't the best way` it's rarely necessary.  Where is it you are using the id?

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it is, I can tell you that `if (inputValue,form.phone.value,form.email.value === '') {` is not doing what you want.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, was swamped in other responsibilities. Added the rest of my JavaScript and images of results.

Comment: Silly mistake, var EleID was being set to the ID of the element clicked and printed along with the contact information, so while the contact information that was to be displayed was a for loop through all contacts, it also printed on each contact the ID of the element clicked, hence when I clicked the second element , a one was printed in both!

Comment: changed the for loop into a if statement to directly compare the ID of the clicked element with the [i] of the contact information to display that information ONLY. which is what I wanted.